# Why HTMLDivElement.constructor.prototype == HTMLDivElement ? it should be prototype object

Tags: javascript, dom

ECMASCRIPT defines prototype object as prototype property of constructor.

Below is copied from ECMA-262:

**4.3.4
constructor
function object that creates and initialises objects
NOTE The value of a constructor‘s "prototype" property is a prototype object that is used to implement inheritance and shared properties.**

Why HTMLDivElement.constructor.prototype == HTMLDivElement ?

if a is a HTMLDivElement object, Object.getPrototypeOf(a) returns HTMLElement while it should return constructor.prototype which is HTMLDivElement.

It's a complete contradict with ECMA standard.

Please help me understanding this concept... Thanks a ton in advance.

[image]

Comment: The premise of your question is actually incorrect: HTMLDivElement.constructor.prototype !== HTMLDivElement

Comment: Well the thing is, DOM elements aren't really JavaScript; they're host elements that mimic JavaScript object behaviors. Firefox, for example, will give very different results.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, actually firefox shows xpconnect for HTMLDIVElement and HTMLElement both. So i am unable to differentiate the results between chrome and firefox. element.__proto__.toString();
[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]
element.__proto__.__proto__.toString();
[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]

Comment: @Praveen `HTMLDivElement.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype == HTMLDivElement.constructor.prototype` in both browsers

Comment: yes that's true, constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype is same but how u r relating it with my question?

Comment: @Pointy, can you help me further by any link ?

Comment: From experiment with chrome and firefox i found that constructor.prototype is not good way to proceed in prototype chain. __proto__ should be used for that purpose and dom model doesn't follow prototype object definition from ES5 standard.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome console shows me:

> HTMLDivElement.constructor.prototype == HTMLDivElement

false

The fact it is displayed in console as `HTMLDivElement` doesn't mean it is a `HTMLDivElement`.

Also: `HTMLDivElement.constructor.prototype == HTMLElement.constructor.prototype`

Comment: a = Object.getPrototypeOf(element)
HTMLDivElement, b = Object.getPrototypeOf(a)
HTMLElement, a.constructor.prototype == b.constructor.prototype
false

Comment: Maybe, you're using some JS library, which modifies Element prototypes?

Comment: `$('#adzerk3')[0] == HTMLDivElement`. This is how they're related

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLDivElement` is defined as interface by w3c (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-div-element.html#htmldivelement), so its implementation depends and vary by browser's vendor.

In Chrome is not a proper constructor (just try to execute `new HTMLDivElement`), in Firefox it's not a constructor at all (it's an object).

Comment: Thanks, I was messing around wondering why, seems to be an illegal constructor. Thanks